# Web server configuration for symfony 1.4

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, symfony

i followed the guide given at the [jobeet project](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Doctrine)  documentations and searched a lot but still get [HTTP 403 Forbidden error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). I do exatly the same as the docs say and followed a few other theads here and from stackoverflow, but still nothing changed. My configurations are just like below:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
  Alias /sf /home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, before downvoting, can anybody please help me?
NOTE: Firewall(iptables and ip6tables) is disabled.
I use centos 6.4 as server
Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Disable selinux `setenforce 0` see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first check the httpd.conf file to find the user running httpd.

Something like this :

User apache
Group apache

And check the rigth on the folder : ll /home/.../web

chown -R apache. /home/.../web

Also check selinux (sestatus or /etc/selinux/config) as lain said